# Create custom CloudWatch metrics for VPN Classic Category

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-cloudwatch

In AWS Production Account, we have a Classic VPN, and this category doesn't have cloudwatch metrics enabled. It is not possible to migrate right away to AWS VPN solutions. How to monitor with cloudwatch metrics the tunnels (Status of tunnels UP/Down) ?
How to put metric data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a script to run the [describe-vpn-connections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-vpn-connections.html) command.

Then check the tunnel status, and push the result of this to a CloudWatch custom metric.